# Intermittent error getsockopt: connection refused error on Http Post

Tags: rest, http, post, go

There are two go apps, one is *stapi* listening on port 8050 and providing RESTful APIs, another is *client* to consume those APIs.

Both are running on different servers, *client* is often getting error when calling APIs with HTTP POST method. Below are few lines from *client* log (real IP replaced with imaginary one)

```
2018/02/17 11:42:58 ERROR: [DoLogin] API Error: [Post https://123.123.123.123:8050/v1/st/verifyuser: dial tcp 123.123.123.123:8050: getsockopt: connection refused]
2018/02/17 11:47:14 ERROR: [CreateAttempt] Error: [Post https://123.123.123.123:8050/v1/userattempts/createattempt: dial tcp 123.123.123.123:8050: getsockopt: connection refused]
```

It is intermittent and making the app unreliable, out of approx 1k request i got such error for approx 50+ request.

Initially *stapi* was listening on all IPs

```
httpSrv := http.Server{
    Addr:         ":8050",
    Handler:      router, // < gin router
    ...
}
```

But after reading the workaroung in [Golang HTTP Post error: connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376472/golang-http-post-error-connection-refused) i modified the *stapi* app and make it listening on different IPs, as shown below

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
stapi     4775  samtech   10u  IPv4 2388179      0t0  TCP 123.123.123.123:8050 (LISTEN)
stapi     4775  samtech   11u  IPv6 2388181      0t0  TCP [::1]:8050 (LISTEN)
stapi     4775  samtech   12u  IPv4 2388183      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8050 (LISTEN)
```

But still the issue is same, what else i should check and fix ? Please suggest.

API is protected with JWT, here is how *client* is making POST requests

```
func (w *OST) DoLogin(c *gin.Context) {
    ...
    ud := stapimodels.UserLogin{}
    err := c.BindJSON(&ud)
    ...
    //call api to save user response
    url := config.AppConfig.APIBaseURL + "st/verifyuser"
    res, err := api.JwtApi.APIPost(url, &ud)
    if err != nil {
            g.Logger.Errorm("DoLogin", "Error: %v", err)
            t.Error("Error", err.Error())
            return
    }
    ...
}

//APIPost - call given apiurl with POST method and pass data
func (j *JwtAPI) APIPost(apiurl string, postdata interface{}) (*APIResult, error) {
        if postdata == nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("postdata is nil")
        }
        jsondata, err := toJSON(postdata)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        resp, err := j.makeRequest(http.MethodPost, apiurl, jsondata)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        res := APIResult{}
        json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&res)
        return &res, nil
}

//makeRequest makes http request for given url with given method
// also inject Authorization Header
func (j *JwtAPI) makeRequest(method, apiurl string, body io.Reader) (*http.Response, error) {
        retry := 0
        //Create []byte buffer from body - so it can be passed in further retries
        var buf []byte
        if body != nil {
                buf, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(body)
        }

        r, err := http.NewRequest(method, apiurl, bytes.NewReader(buf))
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        r.Header.Set("Authorization", "bearer "+j.token.AccessToken)
        r.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

        client := j.getClient()
        resp, err := client.Do(r)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        return resp, nil
}

func (j *JwtAPI) getClient() *http.Client {
        // default timeout (if not set by client)
        timeoutInSec := 10
        if j.Timeout.Seconds() > 0 {
                // client sets timeout, so use it
                timeoutInSec = int(j.Timeout.Seconds())
        }

        client := &http.Client{
                Timeout: time.Second * time.Duration(timeoutInSec),
        }
        return client
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? It's not clear whether you're seeking advice on implementing the logic for dealing with these intermittent failures *on the client* or debugging them *on the server.*

Comment: Oh, and that "magic" number of 1k requests looks suspiciously familiar: by default, on a OS based on Linux, you will have the total number of simultaneously open files for a single process capped at 1024. On a Unix-like system, sockets are treated as files in this regard, so once you have 1024 active connections in your server process, you won't be able to accept the 1025th one. Research [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bgo%5d%20too%20many%20open%20files) for more pointers, and ask for further information if that's indeed looks like your case.

Comment: As @kostix suggests, I would **strongly** recommend looking into your open file descriptor limit.

Comment: @kostix i am trying to find cause for those intermittent failures, so it can be fixed. Regarding open file descripters limit, i had already set it to 65536, hard and soft both.

Comment: @SamTech did you ever solve this? I am having the same intermittent connection refused issue, even after increasing file descriptors limit.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more resilient you should add some retries with back-offs, so even when the connection was refused it is still working.

Connection refused means that the port is not opened. Is there any firewall or proxies in between? The authentication part shouldn't matter here because it doesn't even get to this point.

Some things that you can check:

- Make sure the service is running
- Check for firewall configuration
- Implement retries for resilience
- Is the IP-Address fixed? Is Dynamic DNS used and maybe not updated?

**Package for back-off retrying**

As for implementing the back-off you might try this package:

https://github.com/cenkalti/backoff

It is listing examples on how to use it and it's pretty much exactly what you need:

```
// An operation that may fail.
operation := func() error {
    // do the request here and check the response code (or check the response body depending on your need) . e.g. above 500 should retry, above 400 and below 500, it should be a client side error and retrying might not help much
    return nil // or an error
}

err := Retry(operation, NewExponentialBackOff())
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
    return
}

// Operation is successful.
```

Comment: service is running becuase issue is intermittent and port is reachable, IP address is also fixed. regarging retries logic, can you please provide me link to any guide / standard pattern for it ?

Comment: @SamTech I updated my answer so it includes an example of how you could implement retries on the client side